# Flutter slider not updating when wrapped in ListView but works in column

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, slider, desktop

In this example I have 3 sliders, dragging one slider should update the secondary track of *all* the sliders

This however does not work when the sliders are wrapped with a ListView, notice how the top two tracks do not update until I mouse over them:

[image: Slider ListView]

Changing the ListView to a Column yeilds the desired behaviour:

[image: Slider Column]

Any idea how I can benefit from the virtualisation of ListView and get the on-screen items to update?

```dart
class ShareData with ChangeNotifier {
  double share;
  double shareAvailable;
  ShareData({required this.share, required this.shareAvailable});

  void setShareAvaialble(double value) {
    shareAvailable = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class ShareSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShareSlider({super.key});
  @override
  State<ShareSlider> createState() => _ShareSliderState();
}

class _ShareSliderState extends State<ShareSlider> {
  late List<ShareData> _shares;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _shares = List<ShareData>.generate(3, (index) => ShareData(share: 1.0 / 3, shareAvailable: 1.0 / 3));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView( //<---- Change me to Column
        children: _shares
            .map(
              (s) => ListenableBuilder(
                listenable: s,
                builder: (c, o) => Slider(
                    value: s.share,
                    secondaryTrackValue: s.shareAvailable,
                    onChanged: (e) {
                      s.share = e;
                      for (int i = 0; i < _shares.length; ++i) {
                        _shares[i].setShareAvaialble(1 - e);
                      }
                    }),
              ),
            )
            .toList());
  }
}
```

Expecting all 3 bars to update

Answer (score 0):

You're changing State without calling setState.  Fix that first.

My theory:

- It works when it's a column, because the slider updates, causing the column it's in to update as well.
- It fails in a ListView because the items of a ListView are separately considered, and so the item holding the slider is refreshed, but the neighbors aren't.

Comment: Would the ListenableBuilder builder not update the state when ShareData's notifyListeners() is called?

Originally I did use setstate like this:

`onChanged: (e) {setState(() {
                        s.share = e;
                        for (int i = 0; i < _shares.length; ++i) {
                          _shares[i].shareAvailable = 1 - e;
                        }
                      }}` - unfortunately this does not work either

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, in a slightly hacky way

Using UniqueKey correctly re-renders everything on updates. However this has the side-effect of re-creating the widget the user is currently interacting - breaking dragging.

So instead I use a ValueKey for each widget and only update the keys of the siders we are **not** interacting with:

```dart
class ShareData with ChangeNotifier {
  double share;
  double shareAvailable;
  //This will store a unique key per update
  int updateKey = 0;
  ShareData({required this.share, required this.shareAvailable, required this.updateKey});

  void setShareAvaialble(double value) {
    shareAvailable = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class ShareSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  final int count;

  const ShareSlider({super.key, required this.count});
  @override
  State<ShareSlider> createState() => _ShareSliderState();
}

class _ShareSliderState extends State<ShareSlider> {
  late List<ShareData> _shares;
  int nonce = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _shares =
        List<ShareData>.generate(3, (index) => ShareData(share: 1.0 / 3, shareAvailable: 1.0 / 3, updateKey: nonce++));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _shares.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => ListenableBuilder(
        listenable: _shares[index],
        builder: (c, o) => Slider(

            //Use the update key here
            key: ValueKey(_shares[index].updateKey),
            value: _shares[index].share,
            secondaryTrackValue: _shares[index].shareAvailable,
            onChanged: (e) {
              _shares[index].share = e;
              for (int i = 0; i < _shares.length; ++i) {
                //Update the key of the other siders except the slider we're interacting with
                if (i != index) _shares[i].updateKey = nonce++;
                _shares[i].setShareAvaialble(1 - e);
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
```